# How to restrict access of a file from python

Tags: python

So I made a python phonebook program which allows the user to add contacts, change contact info, delete contacts, etc. and write this data to a text file which I can read from every time the program is opened again and get existing contact data. However, in my program, I write to the text file in a very specific manner so I know what the format is and I can set it up to be read very easily. Since it is all formatted in a very specific manner, I want to prevent the user from opening the file and accidentally messing the data up with even just a simple space. How can I do this?

Comment: In which way the user would open the file? You have to know how your "enemy" would break in, before you can take measure to prevent it.

Comment: Or, you could document the file format so the user could edit the file intelligently.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to prevent the user from opening the file and accidentally messing the data up...

I will advise you not to prevent users from accessing *their own files.* Messing with file permissions might result in some rogue files that the user won't be able to get rid of. **Trust your user**. If they delete or edit a sensitive file, it is their fault. Think of it this way - you have plenty of software installed on your own computer, but how often do you open them in an editor and make some damaging changes? Even if you do edit these files, does the application developer prevent you from doing so?

If you do intent to allow users to change/modify that file give them a good documentation on how to do it. This is the most apt thing to do. Also, make a backup file during run-time (see `tempfile` below) as an added layer of safety. Backups are almost always a good idea.

However, you can take some precautions to hide that data, so that users can't accidentally open them in an editor by double-clicking on it. There are plenty of options to do this including

1. Creating a binary file in a custom format
2. Zipping the text file using [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) module.
3. Using [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile) module to create a temporary file, and zipping it using the previous option. (easy to discard if no changes needs to be saved)
4. Encryption

> #### Everything from here on is not about preventing access, but about hiding the contents of your file

Note that all the above options doesn't have to be mutually exclusive. The advantages of using a zip file is that it will save some space, and it is not easy to read and edit in a text editor (binary data). It can be easily manipulated in your Python Script:

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('eggs.txt') as myfile:
        print(myfile.read())
```

It is as simple as that! A temp file on the other hand, is a volatile (`delete=True/False`) file and can be discarded once you are done with it. You can easily copy its contents to another file or zip it before you close it as mentioned above.

```
with open tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write(b"Binary Data")
```

Again, another easy process. However, you must zip or encrypt it to achieve the final result. Now, moving on to encryption. The easiest way is an XOR cipher. Since we are simply trying to prevent 'readability' and not concerned about security, you can do the following:

#### recommended solution (`XOR` cipher):

```
from itertools import cycle


def xorcize(data, key):
    """Return a string of xor mutated data."""
    return "".join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a, b in zip(data, cycle(key)))


data = "Something came in the mail today"
key = "Deez Nuts"

encdata = xorcize(data, key)
decdata = xorcize(encdata, key)

print(data, encdata, decdata, sep="\n")
```

Notice how small that function is? It is quite convenient to include it in any of your scripts. All your data can be encrypted before writing them to a file, and save it using a file extension such as ".dat" or ".contacts" or any custom name you choose. Make sure it is not opened in an editor by default (such as ".txt", ".nfo").

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to prevent user access to your data storage completely. However, you can either make it more difficult for the user to access your data or actually make it easier not to break it. In the second case, your intention would be to make it clear to the user what the rules are hope that not destroying the data is in the user's own best interest. Some examples:

- **Using a well established, human-readable serialization format, e.g. JSON**. This is often the best solution as it actually allows an experienced user to easily inspect the data, or even modify it. Inexperienced users are unlikely to mess with the data anyways, and an experienced user knowing the format will follow the rules. At the same time, your parser will detect inconsistencies in the file structure.
- **Using a non-human readable, binary format, such as Pickle**. Those files are likely to be left alone by the user as it is pretty clear that they are not meant to be modified outside the program.
- **Using a database, such as MySQL**. Databases provide special protocols for data access which can be used to ensure data consistency and also make it easier to prevent unwanted access.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do in your case is just to choose a new file extension for your format.

It obviously doesn't prevent editing, but it clearly states for user that it has some specific format and probably shouldn't be edited manually. And GUI won't open it by default probably (it will ask what to edit it with).

And that would be enough for any case I can imagine if what you're worrying about is user messing up their own data. I don't think you can win with user who actively tries to mess up their data. Also I doubt any program does anything more. The usual "contract" is that user's data is, well, user's so it can be destroyed by the user.

If you actually won't to prevent editing you could change permissions to forbid editing with os.chmod for example. User would still be able to lift them manually and there will be some time window when you are actually writing, so it will be neither clean nor significantly more effective. And I would expect more trouble than benefit from such a solution.

If you want to actually make it impossible for a user to read/edit a file you can run your process from a different user (or use some heavier like SELinux or other MAC mechanism) and so you could make it really impossible to damage the data (with user's permissions). But it is not worth the effort if it is only about protecting the user from the not-so-catastophic effects of being careless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you file format has a comment character, or can be modified to have one, add these lines to the top of your text file:

```
# Do not edit this file. This file was automatically generated.
# Any change, no matter how slight, may corrupt this file beyond repair.
```

The contact file belongs to your user, not to you. The best you can do is to inform the user. The best you can hope for is that the user will make intelligent use of your product.